# Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest''

Tags: c#, .net, azure, console-application, azure-keyvault

I am trying to get secrets from Azure keyVault on a .Net 4.5 console App , I followed [This tuto](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1430794/Using-Csharp-NET-to-Read-and-Write-from-Azure-Key) , but I got a Bad Request error as mentioned in the title . I have to mention that my console app is newly created , and am using clientId and ClientSecret that belongs to another .Net core web api , that api is able to get secrets successfully , but that's not the case in my console app. Please find below the code am using , the exception is thrown at the instruction of client.GetSecretAsync(vaultAddress,SecretName):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Secret Value from Vault is: { GetVaultValue()}");
        //DoVault();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static string GetVaultValue()
    {
        KeyVaultClient client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(GetToken));
        var vaultAddress = "https://VaultName.vault.azure.net/";
        var secretName = "storageName:NameAccount";
        var secret = client.GetSecretAsync(vaultAddress, secretName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return secret.Value;
    }
    static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
    {
        var clientId = "This-IS-ID";
        var clientSecret = "THIS-iS-my-Secret";
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: This error occurs if you dont have correct permissions

Comment: KeyVaultClient is being deprecated in favor of SecretClient, available in our new package, Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets. We also split KeyClient and CertificateClient into separate packages. See https://aka.ms/valueprop and https://aka.ms/intro for more information. Used with DefaultAzureCredential from Azure.Identity, these are easier to use and do not require code changes from development to production environments.

Comment: @Heath How is it possible to use the new packages in a .net framework project? I'm getting missing dll exceptions (Azure.Core, System.Memory etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `secretName` contains a colon `:`, which led to this error.

Based on my test, we are not allowed to include a colon in the key vault name:

[image]

Please check and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who stills looking an alternative solution. I had the same issue. In my case was the Pfx was expired. The same error occurs when Pfx password is incorrect or Pfx file has an invalid format.

If you try to add it manually in azure KeyVault import form may be you will get this error:

> The content of the specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate cannot be read.
> Verify that the certificate is in valid PKCS#12 format and that the
> submitted password matches the certificate's export password.

I generated a new Pfx file with a non expired date and that solved the Issue.